# Taking out the exponential by lowering its exponent

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

In a book I am studying, while solving something, it does the following thing:

From here
$$ e^{-iωτ}=\frac{1}{2}-iω$$

it goes here

$$ τ=\frac{-arg(1/2-iω)}{ω} $$

However I don't get how this happened. I looked up properties to do it my self, but I can't find it. Can anybody tell me what properties where used to do this?

P.S. I hope this question is valid for this Q&A. I have spent 2 hours trying to solve this, something that I think is really easy.

Comment: We have $e^{i(-\omega \tau)} = \frac 1 2 - i\omega$. By definition of $\mathrm{arg}$, we have $-\omega \tau = \mathrm{arg}(1/2 - i\omega)$. Then you just solve for $\tau$.

Comment: @TrevorNorton now I see what you mean. I was obvious but I still couldn't see it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was from @TrevorNorton comment. I am just writing it down for completion reasons.

The property used is ( based on the definitions of $arg()$ and $e^{θi}$ ):
$$ arg(e^{θi})=θ $$

So by applying $arg()$ on both sides, we can get the exponential out.